# Frame Listener Java

Tags: java, events, awt, frame

why when I go to call the windowsClosing method (WindowEvent e) I get a "java: cannot find symbol" error?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Finestra implements WindowListener {

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        e.getWindow().dispose();
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Class Main:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Grafica g = new Grafica();
        Finestra f1 = new Finestra();
        f1.windowClosing(WindowEvent e);
    }
}
```

The error is given by the main at the time of execution to the line where the WindowsClosing method is called

Comment: `f1.windowClosing(WindowEvent e);` that's not how you call a method

Comment: If you want to add a WindowListener, you probably want to find and call a method called `addWindowListener`.

Comment: f1.windowClosing(WindowEvent e); is not the right way to invoke or call a method. You should create a variable and after initialization, you should pass that variable as an argument in the method.

Comment: Could you show me in lines of code how to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you..
Finestra.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Finestra extends Frame implements WindowListener {

Finestra(){
    addWindowListener(this);

    setSize(400,400);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("closing");
    e.getWindow().dispose();
}

public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
}

public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("hello");
}

public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
}

public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
}

public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
}

public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
}
```

}

Main.java

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  new Finestra();

}
```

}

I don't understand the Grafica class you used but if you want to use it for frame you can extend frame in Finestra class!
 I hope it will help you!